# Amazon S3 mysterious(unwanted) files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently created my first bucket on S3. I had a folder named backups there which when I opened I saw these about 300 small(from few bytes to 4 or so Kbs) in that folder. I hadn't even uploaded anything yet.

I delete those files but they reappear again after some time.

Can anyone please explain what is(might be) going on. The content of those files is something about encryption stuff.

You can see [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaTUq.png)

If i don't delete them they are just gonna multiply and use my space.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: S3 doesn't generate files by itself. It could be something like CloudTrail logs going into the bucket, the bucket could be public and someone is storing something, or you have a process doing it. Check your CloudTrail logs (which are stored in an S3 bucket) to work out how they're getting there. You may need to enable object level logging or something like that, I've never tried it, I think it's a configuration setting on the bucket.

Comment: I checked and made some changes. I will wait till those files are regenerated to see if it was the issue with naming folder name as `backup` which i should have given something like `logs` etc

Comment: @Tim You were right those are logs. Thank you.

Comment: I will post an answer to your question so you can accept it. That prevents others having to come in and have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like CloudTrail logs to me, or perhaps some other type of log. I think you've configured your account to store logs in that bucket.

Comment: These appear to be [S3 bucket access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#server-log-keyname-format).   A bucket that writes its logs to itself is a configuration I occasionally see users set up, which isn't a good idea... such a bucket will write logs to itself indefinitely since creation of each new log file creates a log entry, which will result in creation of a future log file, which creates a new log entry...